# How to add configuration set to AWS SES emails using aws-ses gem Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, amazon-ses, amazon-simple-email-service

I am able to send emails successfully using aws-ses gem but I wanted to add configuration set while sending email. Below are my configurations. Help me in adding configuration set.

Gem which I am using

```
gem "aws-ses", git: "https://github.com/zebitex/aws-ses.git", ref: "78-sigv4-problem"
```

config/initializers/amazon_ses.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :ses, AWS::SES::Base,
access_key_id: "abc",
secret_access_key: "pqr",
signature_version: 4
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: there is official AWS SES gem that you can use

Comment: Hi - did you find a way to do this? All I've found so far is to adapt the code from the `aws-sdk-rails` gem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following config

```
# add these gems to Gemfile
gem 'aws-sdk-rails', '>= 2.1.0'
gem 'aws-sdk-sesv2'
```

then create initializer file: `config/initializers/ses_aws.rb`

```
  creds = Aws::Credentials.new(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_key)

  Aws::Rails.add_action_mailer_delivery_method(
    :ses,
    credentials: creds,
    region: 'ap-southeast-1' # or any region
  )
```

update config file `config/environments/production.rb` (you can update your development.rb too for testing)

```
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :ses
```

you can send emails like normally, for example: `UserMailer.send_confirmation_email(user_id).deliver`

Comment: configuration set is a group of rules which we can add to email header using Amazon SES. Is there a way to add configuration set using these gems? so that for each email sent we can set configuration set in the header @SaiqulHaq

Comment: I didn't add any configuration set on my app. it just works

Comment: configuration set is an optional parameter to specify a set of rules and event destinations in Amazon SES. But not sure on how to add config set with these gems